# Trying to show that $f$ is not a zero divisor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Consider the ring $R=\dfrac {k[x,y,z,t]}{(y(xt-yz))}$. Consider the polynomial $f=t(y^3-x^2z)$. Is $f$ a non zero divisors of $R$?

How do we check this? I know that if $f$ is a zero divisor then some multiple of $f$ will lie in the ideal $(y(xt-yz))$. I think we have to use that polynomial ring is PID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** All elements involved are prime in the polynomial ring, and pairwise coprime.

Comment: Could you please provide some more details?

Comment: @Dontknowanything If $R$ is a UFD, and $p_i$ ($1\le i\le 4$) are distinct primes, then $p_3p_4$ is not a zerodivisor on $R/(p_1p_2)$: if $p_3p_4a\in(p_1p_2)$ then $p_1p_2\mid p_3p_4a$, so $p_1p_2\mid a$. Is this clear enough?

Comment: @Dontknowanything From $p_1\mid p_3p_4a$ what do you get? (Don't forget that we are in a UFD!)

Comment: ohh yes..due to $p_i$ primes,$p_1p_2$ will divide $a$.Its clear now..Thank you.

Comment: :One more doubt:what is a quick way to say that $(y^3-x^2z)$ is irreducible?(Probably because $z$ is linear in expression)

Comment: @Dontknowanything Yes, that poly is of degree one in $z$, so it is irreducible.

Answer (score 2):

For $ f $ to be a zero divisor in $ R $, it is necessary and sufficient for an element $ g \in k[x, y, z, t] $ and $ g \notin (y(xt - yz)) $ to exist such that $ fg \in (y(xt - yz)) $. However, $ f $ shares no divisors with the generator of the principal ideal (polynomial rings over fields are unique factorization domains), therefore such a $ g $ is necessarily contained in the ideal, and $ f $ is not a zero divisor.

Comment: Ahh i see..thank you.